# Why do most Stack Overflow users not like to report where they live?

Tags: discussion

I just created a query to see where SO users live:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/184576/where-are-most-of-stackoverflow-users

And I was amazed that 2.5M out of 3M users have an empty location field.

On top of that, a huge number of users don't provide any contact information (that's my personal observation, which isn't backed up by a query).

Just curious. Why does SO have such a strong culture of anonymity?

Comment: It gets worse: the provided address information need not be correct. Witness mine. And *my* reason is that I want to be in control of how much the internet can bother me, rather than letting the internet be in control. Mind you, a really determined person could find me from my profile data, but it would take a little doing. Frankly I'm always surprised when people *do* provide contact information ... I always wonder what they are thinking.

Comment: It's called privacy

Comment: Um, not to be creepy @dmckee, but your email is four clicks and no typing off your profile page...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog

Comment: Why do you need to know where I live?  Is "Earth" not specific enough for you? :P

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Has InSpire made it easier than it used to be? That's progress for you. Last time I did it, it took about five minutes of digging. Anyway, I've never been fanatical about it, I just want a barrier to casual contact which will deter the gentle folk from bothering me without good cause.

Comment: On a site where you "ask questions, get answers, no distractions", that's "not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat", doesn't it make sense that most people don't want to share personal information?

Comment: Because people like problems :(

Comment: "I just created a query to see where SO users live". Creepy `:P`

Answer (score 7):

This is just my opinion, so don't take it too seriously.

I think most people on Stack Overflow have some kind of engineering/science background. With that being said, I think we (hopefully) have a better understanding of internet security/privacy issues. That leads me to think that we generally prefer to give as little information as we can about our personal info, especially on the internet.

If you go on a more social network oriented website populated by teenagers, you might see a higher contact info completion rate. I'm almost willing to bet that there is an association between contact info completion rate, and age + education. Don't quote me on this though. I personally feel that I definitely used to put a lot more personal info when I was young(er).

Comment: It's also easier to troll and be a jerk if the people you're targeting can't find you. :D  I feel like an interesting study would be to find out if rude comments are more likely to come from those with a gravatar or those who put their face front and center...

Comment: Social networks are about ... well, socializing, so it makes sense that people are more inclined to share personal information there.